# Location settings for LocationRequest

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my app, I want to get the the location of the device via GPS. Ok, I declare
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`
in manifest and when the app start, the user is asked to allow GPS.

When I read [Android dok](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings#prompt), there are two options:

1. All location settings are satisfied:

   ```
   task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
       // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
       // location requests here.
       // ...
     }
   });
   ```
2. Location settings are not satisfied:

   ```
   task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
           // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
           // by showing the user a dialog.
           try {
             // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
             // and check the result in onActivityResult().
             ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
             resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                   REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
           } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
             // Ignore the error.
           }
        }
     }
   });
   ```

It seems, that there are two kinds of resources, one, I have to declare in manifest and another kind, I have to ask for at runtime.

1. Did I get it right?
2. Why this distinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`, an app tells the Android system that I will require this permission in app to operate as intended.

Thereafter, if permission you require is listed as [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), then system will ask for the permission to the user, else system will grant you that permission at runtime(which means you need to ask for the permission and system will take action as required).

This permission rules apply for API level 23+.

If user grants you the permission, then you'll be able to access user's that information.

In case of location, you need to do the extra check(your second point of the question) because locations can only be checked for, by the system when the location setting is enabled. That is, the location symbol that comes in list of WiFi symbol, Mobile data symbol.

**EDIT:**
If you omit the code snippet of checking location settings, then if the user's location is off like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtHIc.png), then you will not get location.

And there is no such permission as `"android.permission.LOCATION_SETTINGS_ENABLED"`.

Comment: Ok, but when I omit the `resolvable.startResolutionForResult(...)` thing, my location request works well anyway, and when I follow the  `resolvable.startResolutionForResult(...)` way, the user gets three dialog boxes asking for permission/settings (Who wants that? I didn't even read the second question.).  But anyway, when I need location settings to be enabled to be able to determin current location, why not `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_SETTINGS_ENABLED"/>` to be consistent?

Comment: Ok, I will check this.

Comment: You are right, I have to make sure, that location settings are enabled. Then I will do it this way. Thank's.